# MySql Commands out of sync when storing stored procedure result in dataframe

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to import data from a MySql database into a pandas dataframe by calling a stored procedure.

But I am getting the following error which I do not understand after the exception is thrown it seems like the data is actually in the dataframe. So how can I get rid of this exception?

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

import_data_query = "CALL my_scheme.my_procedure(NULL);"

connection_string = "mysql+mysqlconnector://***:***@localhost/my_scheme"

engine = create_engine(connection_string)

df = pd.read_sql_query(sql=import_data_query, con=engine)

engine.dispose()
```

The exception I am getting:

```
Exception during reset or similar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 693, in _finalize_fairy
    fairy._reset(pool)
  File "C:\Users\*\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 880, in _reset
    pool._dialect.do_rollback(self)
  File "C:\Users\*\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mysql\base.py", line 2302, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
  File "C:\Users\*\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 386, in rollback
    self._cmysql.rollback()
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

Comment: MySQL does not have *schema* in the same way other RDBMS's do. Really, you are connecting to the database object.

Answer (score 1):

For stored procedures, you need to use the connection object per [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#calling-stored-procedures) to access [`callproc`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-callproc.html):

```
conn = engine.raw_connection()
cur = conn.cursor()

res = cur.callproc("my_procedure", args=(None,))   # None SHOULD TRANSLATE AS NULL
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = [i[0] for i in res.description])
```

Alternatively, directly interface with DB-API, here being `MySQL.connector`:

```
import mysql.connector

myconn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', database='mydatabase',
                                 user='***', password='***')
mycur = myconn.cursor()

results = mycur.callproc("my_procedure", args=(None,))
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=[i[0] for i in results.description])

mycur.close()
myconn.close()
```